# Probability that two random variables have a product greater than 1

Tags: probability, random-variables, density-function

I have two independent random variables $X$ and $Y,$ defined using the following formulas, respectively: 
$F_X(x)=(1/2)x,$ where $0<x<2;$ and $f_Y(y) = (2/9)y,$ where $0<y<3.$ What is the probability that $XY \ge 1$? `

Comment: Can you reformulate ?

Comment: I reformatted because I realized the rest was cutting off. This is essentially all the information I have. I'm not really sure how to do this with two variables. I hope this context helps a little.

Comment: $f_Y$ is not a pdf. Are they independent.

Comment: Yes X and Y are independent

Comment: General approach: $f_{XY}(x,y) = f_X(x)f_Y(y)$. Integrate this over the subset of the domain for which $xy \geq 1$. Can you write out these steps and indicate where you are stuck?

Comment: That is the general track I was on but the issue I ran into was trying to figure out the domain subset.

Comment: Since $X$ and $Y$ are both positive (with probability $1$), $xy \geq 1$ iff $y \geq 1/x$, so it's the region above the graph of $y = 1/x$, intersected with the support of $f_{XY}$.

Comment: So do I integrate the X function from 0 to 2 and the y function from 0 to X?

Comment: Edited your question for easier reading. Please check that I did not change your meaning. I suppose you intend to give the CDF of X and the PDF of Y. **Please check that.**

Answer (score 1):

For $XY\ge 1$, since $Y\le 3$, $X\ge \frac{1}{3}$. Similarly$Y\ge\frac{1}{2}$.

[image]

$P(XY\ge 1)$

$=\int_{\frac{1}{3}}^{2}\int_{\frac{1}{x}}^{3}P(X=x)P(Y=y)dydx$

$=\frac{1}{9}\int_{\frac{1}{3}}^{2}\int_{\frac{1}{x}}^{3}xy\cdot dydx$

$=\frac{1}{18}\int_{\frac{1}{3}}^{2}x(9-\frac{1}{x^2})dx$

$=\frac{1}{4}(4-\frac{1}{9})-\frac{1}{18}\ln 6$

$=\frac{35}{36}-\frac{1}{18}\ln 6$

Comment: Should be $f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ instead of $P(X=x)P(Y=y)$ (the latter is zero for all $x,y$). Also as noted by copper.hat in the comments above, the formula given for $f_Y(y)$ cannot be right, because it doesn't integrate to $1$.

Comment: Is it possible given the way this was formatted that the equation for the random variables of X and Y are the antiderivatives of the actual functions?